# stdout readlines for windows hangs python 3.4

Tags: python

i have a problem with the below script which is used to connect to one of our nodes using ssh and perform a command. when i execute the last line of the script the script hangs. could you please advise if there is a solution in order to solve this issue?

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('IP',port= 22, username='xxx',password='xxx')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('xxxx')
output=stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: What does xxx stand for? If you manually ssh to the host and execute xxx, does it hang, or wait for input? My guess is that xxx waits for input, but your script does not feed xxx with the requested input.

Comment: Hi Michael. Yes, the command exucetud first then i try to emport the output using stdout. But when this command exucuted the script hang. I'm facing this issue only when i perform this into windows node. But when i do the same on linux node it is performed successfuly.

Comment: When on  the linux shell prompt, try to execute cat | xxx | cat, and see if it hangs. Some programs work differently if they are attached to a tty (terminal) than to a pipe.